# Troubleshooting Null Reference in EmptyDataTemplate OnRowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to figure out why I am getting a null reference exception error on similar code that works fine in other pages. What is baffling to me is that if I comment out certain 'if' clauses, the null reference error points to different lines. If I enter invalid data that should trigger my data validation clauses, those kick off the expected error message which tells me the row itself isn't null and the controls/values that are being validated aren't null. What gets me is that the `if (gvrow == null) {return;}` line gets a squiggly saying that `gvrow == null` is always false (therefore the `{return;}` will never get executed), but just by commenting that line out, the null reference error points to the closing brace of the OnRowCommand block instead of just before the else clause of the data validation.

EDIT: I refactored the common part of the OnRowCommand method into a private method with the same event being triggered from the Footer Row. Now, the null exception points to `GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("Notes", txtNotes.Text);`

ASPX

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Timecards.aspx.cs" Inherits="ProjectLogic.Timecards" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <br/>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="lside">
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmployee" runat="server" Text="Select Employee:" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEmployee" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ddlActiveEmployeeSQL" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                                    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="EmployeeID">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="<--Select Employee-->" Value="" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>From: </td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TxtFrom" runat="server" CssClass="DateBox"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        <td>To: </td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox  ID="TxtTo" runat="server" CssClass="DateBox"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br/>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnSearch" Text="Search"/>
            </div> <!-- end div left -->
            <div id="rside">
            </div> <!-- end div right -->
        </div> <!-- end div wrapper -->
    <br/>

    <asp:GridView ID="GvTimecards" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  ShowFooter="True" AllowSorting="True" OnDataBound="GvTimecards_DataBound" OnRowCommand="GvTimecards_OnRowCommand"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="TimecardID" DataSourceID="GridViewTimecardSQL">
<Columns>...</Columns> <!-- ItemTemplates, EditItemTemplates, FooterTemplates -->
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table border="1">
                <tr style="background-color:silver">
                    <th class="NoPrint"></th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Hours</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th>Project&nbsp;#</th>
                    <th>Project Name</th>
                    <th>Release&nbsp;#</th>
                    <th>#&nbsp;Panels</th>
                    <th>#&nbsp;Sheets</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="NoPrint"><asp:LinkButton ID="LbTimeCardEmpty" runat="server" CommandName="EmptyInsert" Text="Add&nbsp;Entry" /></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TxtDate" runat="server" CssClass="DateBox AlignRight alert-warning" Text='<%# DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()%>' />
                        <asp:CompareValidator id="EditDueDateValidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
                                              ControlToValidate="TxtDate" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date.">
                        </asp:CompareValidator>
                    </td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DdlTaskDesc" runat="server" DataSourceID="DdlTaskDescSQL" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                            DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="TimecardTaskID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("TimeCardTaskID") %>' AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="<--Select Task-->" Value="" />
                        </asp:DropDownList></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TxtHours" runat="server" CssClass="NumBox AlignRight alert-warning"  Text="0.00" /></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TxtNotes" runat="server"   /></td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DdlProjectsById" runat="server" DataSourceID="DdlProjectsByIdSQL" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                          DataTextField="ProjectID" DataValueField="ProjectID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProjectID") %>' 
                                          OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlEmptyProjectsById_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="<--Select Project-->" Value="" />
                    </asp:DropDownList></td>
                    <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DdlProjectsByName" runat="server" DataSourceID="DdlProjectsByNameSQL" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                                          DataTextField="ProjectName" DataValueField="ProjectID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ProjectID") %>' 
                                          OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlEmptyProjectsByName_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="<--Select Project-->" Value="" /></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TxtRelease" runat="server" CssClass="NumBox AlignRight"  /></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TxtNumPanels" runat="server" CssClass="NumBox AlignRight" Text="0" /></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TxtNumSheets" runat="server" CssClass="NumBox AlignRight" Text="0" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
<PagerTemplate>...</PagerTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
<!-- SQL DataSources here -->
</asp:Content>
```

ASPX.CS CodeBehind (refactored common code from OnRowCommand being triggered from FooterTemplate or EmptyDataTemplate)

```
protected void GvTimecards_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "FooterInsert" && Page.IsValid)
        {
            GridViewRow gvrow = GvTimecards.FooterRow;
            if (gvrow != null)
            {
                RowInsert(gvrow);
            }
        }

        if (e.CommandName == "EmptyInsert" && Page.IsValid)
        {
            GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow) GvTimecards.Controls[0].Controls[0];
            if (gvrow != null)
            {
                RowInsert(gvrow);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RowInsert(GridViewRow gvRow)
    {
        GridViewRow gvrow = gvRow;
        TextBox txtDate = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("TxtDate");
        DropDownList ddlDescription = (DropDownList)gvrow.FindControl("DdlTaskDesc");
        TextBox txtHours = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("TxtHours");
        TextBox txtNotes = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("TxtNotes");
        DropDownList ddlProjectId = (DropDownList)gvrow.FindControl("DdlProjectsById");
        TextBox txtRelNo = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("TxtReleaseNo");
        TextBox txtNumPanels = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("TxtNumPanels");
        TextBox txtNumSheets = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("TxtNumSheets"); 

        //Data Validation
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddlEmployee.SelectedValue)) // no employee selected. Control is in MainContent, not in GridView
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "error",
                "alert('Please select Employee before adding Timecard.');", true);
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddlDescription.SelectedValue)) // no task description selected
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "error",
                "alert('Please select Timecard Description.');", true);
        }
        else if ((ddlDescription.SelectedValue == "2" || ddlDescription.SelectedValue == "8") &&
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddlProjectId.SelectedValue)) // non-project task and project selected
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "error",
                "alert('Non-project Description and Project # selected. Please change Description or use <Select Project>.');",
                true);
        } 
        else
        {
            GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Clear();
            GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("EmployeeID", ddlEmployee.SelectedValue);
            GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("Date", txtDate.Text);
            GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("TimecardTaskID", ddlDescription.SelectedValue);
            GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("Hours", txtHours.Text);
            GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("Notes", txtNotes.Text); // null exception here
            GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("ProjectID", ddlProjectId.SelectedValue);
            GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("ReleaseNo", txtRelNo.Text);
            GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("NumPanels", txtNumPanels.Text);
            GridViewTimecardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("NumSheets", txtNumSheets.Text);
            GridViewTimecardSQL.Insert();
        }
    }
```

If it's possibly something not referenced in the GridView's Insert SQL, that's below.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="GridViewTimecardSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectLogicTestConnectionString %>" 
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblTimecard] WHERE [TimecardID] = @TimecardID" 
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblTimecard] ([EmployeeID], [Date], [TimeCardTaskID], [Hours], [Notes], [ProjectID], [ReleaseNo], [NumPanels], [NumSheets]) 
VALUES (@EmployeeID, @Date, @TimeCardTaskID, @Hours, @Notes, @ProjectID, @ReleaseNo, @NumPanels, @NumSheets)" 
SelectCommand="SELECT tc.TimecardID, tc.EmployeeID, e.Name, tc.Date, tc.TimeCardTaskID, tt.Description, tc.Hours, tc.Notes, tc.ProjectID, 
    p.ProjectName, tc.ReleaseNo, tc.NumPanels, tc.NumSheets 
    FROM tblTimecard AS tc 
    INNER JOIN tblEmployee AS e ON tc.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN tblProject AS p ON tc.ProjectID = p.ProjectID 
    INNER JOIN tblTimecardTask AS tt ON tc.TimeCardTaskID = tt.TimecardTaskID 
    WHERE (tc.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID) AND (tc.Date &gt;= @FromDate) AND (tc.Date &lt;= @ToDate) 
    ORDER BY tc.ProjectID, tc.Date" 
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblTimecard] SET  [Date] = @Date, [TimeCardTaskID] = @TimeCardTaskID, [Hours] = @Hours, 
    [Notes] = @Notes, [ProjectID] = @ProjectID, [ReleaseNo] = @ReleaseNo, [NumPanels] = @NumPanels, [NumSheets] = @NumSheets WHERE [TimecardID] = @TimecardID">
 <DeleteParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="TimecardID" Type="Int32" />
 </DeleteParameters>
 <InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="EmployeeID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="TimeCardTaskID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Hours" Type="Decimal" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectID" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="ReleaseNo" Type="Byte" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="NumPanels" Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="NumSheets" Type="Int32" />
 </InsertParameters>
 <SelectParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEmployee" Name="EmployeeID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TxtFrom" Name="FromDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="" />
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TxtTo" Name="ToDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" DefaultValue="" />
 </SelectParameters>
 <UpdateParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="TimeCardTaskID" Type="Int32" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="Hours" Type="Decimal" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectID" Type="Int32" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="ReleaseNo" Type="Byte" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="NumPanels" Type="Int32" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="NumSheets" Type="Int32" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="TimecardID" Type="Int32" />
 </UpdateParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typos will get you each and every time. Problem was the Textbox for Release # was labeled "txtRelease" and I was telling FindControl to look for "txtReleaseNo".